# Massive performance problems running applications in hyper v

Tags: c#, .net, performance, console-application, hyper-v

**Update**: Se bottom: Added CreateArticleRelations code example.

Ok, this is a tricky one. I am experiencing a massive performance problem in hyper-v when it comes to preview and production environments.

First of all, here is the setup.

.NET 4.0 on all servers.

**Preview**

Webserver : Virtual machine, 8gb ram, 4 cpu, windows server 2008 r2 (64)

Database: Virtual server, 6gb ram, 2 cpu, windows server 2008 r2 (64)

**Production**:

Webserver: Virtual machine, 8gb ram, 4 cpu, windows server 2008 r2 (64)

Database: Physical machine, 48 gb ram, 16 cpu, windows server 2008 r2 (64)

This is a B2B shop running on these. And when running integration for one product the results are mind blowing for me. I will provide pictures.

Running for one product in preview takes: 83 seconds for everything to update.
Running for one product in production takes 301 seconds (!) for everything to update. Same product!

If I run this locally it takes about 40 seconds to complete.

I have ran dotTrace profiling remote on the both servers to actually see what is taking time. I use EnterpriseLibrary for logging, umbraco for cms and uCommerce as a commerce platform. Look at the picture example below of one finding I have seen.

[image]

First of all, CreateArticleRelations takes 140 seconds on the production server but only 46 on the preview. Same product, same data. Then to the really funky stuff. On the production site at the top we see enterpriselogging taking 64 seconds, but on the preview run it is way down so can't even say it taking absolutley no time.

The implementation of the logging looks like this.

```
      private string LogMessage(string message, int priority, string category, TraceEventType severity, int code, int skipFrames = 2)
  {
     //Check if "code" exists in eCommerceB2B.LogExceptions
     var dbf = new ThirdPartSources();
     var exeptions = dbf.GetLogExeptions();
     foreach (var exeption in exeptions)
     {
        if (code.ToString() == exeption)
           return DateTime.Now.ToString();
     }


     try
     {
        var stack = new StackTrace(skipFrames);

        if (_logWriter.IsLoggingEnabled())
        {
           var logEntry = new LogEntry
                              {
                                 Title =
                                     stack.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName + " " +
                                     stack.GetFrame(0).GetMethod(),
                                 Message = message,
                                 Priority = priority,
                                 Severity = severity,
                                 TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                                 EventId = code
                              };

           logEntry.Categories.Add(category);

           _logWriter.Write(logEntry);

           return logEntry.TimeStampString;
        }
```

Logging is set up to a rolling flatfile and a database. I have tried to disable the logging and that saves about 20 seconds, but still the LogMessage is up at the top.

This has blown my mind for days and i can't seem to find a solution. Sure I can remove logging completely but I wan't to find the cause of the problem.

What bothers me is that for example running one method (CreateArticleRelations) takes almost 4 times as long on the production server. The cpu level is never over 30 % and 5 gb ram is available. The applications is ran as a console application.

Someone please save me! :) I can provide more data if needed. My bet is that is has something to do with the virtual server but I have no idea what to check.

**Update:**

Per comment, i tried to comment out the LogMessage completly. It saves about 100 seconds totally which tells me that something is terribly wrong. Still taking 169 seconds to create the relations vs 46 seconds in preview, and in preview logging is still enabled. What can be wrong to enterprise library to make it behave this way? And still, why i code running 4x slower on the production server? Se image after I remove LogMessage. It is from PRODUCTION.

[image]

CreateArticleRelations

```
        private void CreateArticleRelations(Product uCommerceProduct, IStatelessSession session)
    {
        var catalogues = _jsbArticleRepository.GetCustomerSpecificCatalogue(uCommerceProduct.Sku).CustomerRelations;
        var defaultCampaignName = _configurationManager.GetValue(ConfigurationKeys.UCommerceDefaultCampaignName);
        var optionalArticleCampaignName = _configurationManager.GetValue(ConfigurationKeys.UCommerceDefaultOptionalArticleCampaignName);

        var categoryRelations =
            session.Query<CategoryProductRelation>()
                .Fetch(x => x.Category)
                .Fetch(x => x.Product)
                .Where(
                    x =>
                    x.Category.Definition.Name == _customerArticleCategory && x.Product.Sku == uCommerceProduct.Sku)
                .ToList();

        var relationsAlreadyAdded = _categoryRepository.RemoveCataloguesNotInRelation(catalogues, categoryRelations,
                                                                                      session);

        _categoryRepository.SetArticleCategories(session, relationsAlreadyAdded, uCommerceProduct, catalogues,
                                                 _customerCategories, _customerArticleCategory,
                                                 _customerArticleDefinition);

        //set campaigns and optional article
        foreach (var jsbArticleCustomerRelation in catalogues)
        {
            // Article is in campaign for just this user
            if (jsbArticleCustomerRelation.HasCampaign)
            {
                _campaignRepository.CreateCampaignAndAddProduct(session, jsbArticleCustomerRelation, defaultCampaignName);
            }
            else // remove the article from campaign for user if exists
            {
                _campaignRepository.DeleteProductFromCampaign(session, jsbArticleCustomerRelation, defaultCampaignName);
            }

            // optional article
            if(jsbArticleCustomerRelation.IsOptionalArticle) 
            {               
                _campaignRepository.CreateCampaignAndAddProduct(session, jsbArticleCustomerRelation, optionalArticleCampaignName);
            }
            else
            {
                _campaignRepository.DeleteProductFromCampaign(session, jsbArticleCustomerRelation, optionalArticleCampaignName);
            }
        }            
    }
```

We hit the database almost on every row here in some way. For example in the DeleteProductFromCampaign the following code take 43 seconds in the preview environment and 169 seconds in the production environment.

```
        public void DeleteProductFromCampaign(IStatelessSession session, JSBArticleCustomerRelation jsbArticleCustomerRelation, string campaignName)
    {
        var productTarget =
            session.Query<ProductTarget>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(
                       x =>
                       x.CampaignItem.Campaign.Name == jsbArticleCustomerRelation.CustomerNumber &&
                       x.CampaignItem.Name == campaignName &&
                       x.Sku == jsbArticleCustomerRelation.ArticleNumber);

        if (productTarget != null)
        {
            session.Delete(productTarget);
        }
    }
```

So this code for example runs 4x slower on the production server. The biggest difference between the servers are that the production (physical) server in set up with noumerous instances and I am using one of them (20 gb om ram).

Comment: Comment out all the code in your LogMessage and test performance one more time. 20 seconds for logging is really TOO much.

Comment: Commented out the LogMessage and 100 seconds was removed. So it is something with enterpriselibrary then. Bu still. CreateArticleRelations take 169 seconds. Se updated post.

Comment: _"why is code running 4x slower on the production server?"_ - that totally depends on what the code is doing. It's nice to know your `CreateArticleRelations()` method takes 169 seconds to complete, but nobody can do anything about that if we don't know what happens in there. Are you accessing network, database or disk, or doing CPU-intensive work, and so on. You will have to profile _where_ the bottleneck is, show the appropriate code and then _we_ can take a look how to improve the performance of that piece.

Comment: The problem is that it seems like every bit takes a little bit longer, but say for example CreateArticleRelations, which is a foreach loop and for every loop contains 2 database queries. I will post the CreateArticleRelations code if that helps. Still, the logging takes no time at all on the preview server.

Comment: Maybe accessing to database is very slow on production? This can be due to network issues.

Comment: I do not think that it is network related. We have other database queries (from a web) on the same server that works just fine. It is only when i run console applications that execute code. Single select from code is faster, but say 100 queries in a loop is very very slower.

Comment: Few pointers to help you troubleshoot: 
* Check the number of snapshots/checkpoints you might have the Virtual Machine. Having a lot of them can slow down writing to VHDs
* Run PerfMon on host to identify the bottleneck. Are all the processor cores being used by Hyper-V VM, is their a bottleneck on either storage or network...